# combobox /dropdownlist in grid view c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a newbie to c#.net winforms application. I have a data grid wch displays some data and out of which one of the column shud be made a dropdownlist or combobox. how do I use that in my code. please help.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].OwningColumn;
   sql = "select NAME FROM Suppliers";
   BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
   bsource.DataSource = obj.SqlDataTable(sql);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
   combo.HeaderText = "Select Supplier";
 }
```

I want to populate the 3rd column of the data grid with supplier name  from the corresponding suppliers table.The data grid view is already populated with data from a join query and one of the field is Supplier(wch I mwant to convert to a dropdown or combo box). let me know if you need any further info for clarifications.

```
        I Modified my code as follows:

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        combo.HeaderText = "Suppliers";
        //execute sql data adapter to get supplier values
        DataTable dt = obj.SqlDataTable("select NAME from CUSTOMERS");
        foreach (DataRow supplier in dt.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            combo.Items.Add(supplier[0]);
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);
```

now am getting a null reference exception at " dt.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows"
 . plz help. I am not sure if am missing something.

Comment: you need to lookup how to use ItemTemplate that's a good start it's not that difficult

Comment: I am not using any item templates. I just dragged and dropped a grid view into my winform and populated the grid view based a on a complex join query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
string strcon = @"Data Source=kp;Initial Catalog=Name;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCmb;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            grdcmd();
        }
        public void grdcmd()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con.Open();
            string qry = "Select * from Dbname";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, strcon);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvCmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                dgvCmb.Items.Add(row["Fname"].ToString());
            }
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCmb);
        }
```

Comment: thanks. I modified my code as shown above. I am getting a null reference exception and am not sure if I am wrong some where.

Comment: where you get null exception

Comment: Can you plz tell me why my dropdownlist in my grid view keeps on increasing on every key press.     if(dataGridView1.Columns.IndexOfc(combo) < 0)
                    {

                        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);
                    }

Comment: when I tried debugging putting a breakpoint at if condition, it always showed me index value = -1 Can anyone help

Comment: row index and column index two different thing in grid view where you click in grid view that show the index of row or column you write in your code